# How to execute predefined oracle query that is stored in table column with predefined input stored procedure parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select ruleid 
from fins_stiprulemasternew 
where PRODUCTID = p_Productcode
  and p_BSCORE < BSCOREFROM;
```

Above query I'm storing in table column.

This statement I'm executing in another stored procedure where `p_Productcode` and `p_BSCORE` are input parameters...

```
procedure sp_validate
    (p_Productcode    varchar2 := NULL,
     p_crd_source     varchar2 := NULL,
     p_dealercode     varchar2 := NULL,
     p_CLI_RES_PIN    varchar2 := NULL,
     p_emiamount      number   := NULL,
     p_tenure         number   := NULL,
     p_txnamount      number   := NULL,
     p_BSCORE         number   := NULL,
     p_CIBIL          number   := NULL,
     p_ACTIVATIONDAYS number   := NULL,
     P_OUTPUT        OUT sys_refcursor
  )
c_sql varchar2(500);
 r_ruleid     varchar2(20);
 c_sql := 'select ruleid FROM fins_stiprulemasternew where PRODUCTID = p_Productcode and p_BSCORE < BSCOREFROM';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE c_sql into r_ruleid;
```

When executing this, I'm getting an error:

> "P_BSCORE": invalid identifier

Comment: I removed the mysql tag. Your code example shows you are using Oracle database, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that none of the parameters declared as part of your procedure are in scope for your dynamic SQL statement.  You'd need to pass the values to your SQL statement somehow.

Assuming that you updated the SQL statement stored in the table to use bind variables and that you know the number and order in which the bind variables appear in the SQL statement

```
select ruleid 
from fins_stiprulemasternew 
where PRODUCTID = :p_Productcode
  and :p_BSCORE < BSCOREFROM
```

You could do

```
  OPEN p_output
   FOR c_sql
 USING p_productCode, p_bScore
```

If your actual goal is to be able to use all of the parameters being passed in to your procedure in an arbitrary order, you could potentially read the SQL statement from the table, run a series of `replace` commands to replace `p_productCode` with the value of `p_productCode` that was passed in to the procedure (making sure to escape quotes correctly), and then run that.  That would require a hard parse on every execution which will be a performance hit but if this is a low-volume situation, that hit may be acceptable.

If you care about performance and need full flexibility, you'd need to convert the data to use bind variables, use `dbms_sql` to parse the statement, describe the bind variables, and then bind appropriate values.  That's a lot more complicated than either of the other approaches but it will be the most performant.